# How to search for specific flight numbers?

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines, code-share

I am planning a trip from Melbourne to Seattle. I would like as much of it as possible to be on an AA ticket (even if on another airline's plane).

I can buy tickets with Qantas that go MEL-SYD-LAX-SEA and back, with the last LAX-SEA part on Alaska.

I can buy the MEL-SYD-LAX and back legs through the AA website with the MEL->SYD leg treated as a Qantas ticket, but the remaining legs as American.

I can buy the LAX-SEA return trip through American as an American ticket (on a Alasa plane).

I would buy these separately, but I'm worried about having to recheckin and missing connections since they are separate tickets.

I'd like to buy these as a single ticket. When I do the combined search on any online agency I can't find this option, only the same airplanes bought through Qantas. Is there any search engine where I can tell it to look for specific flight numbers?

To be specific, I'm looking at AA7407 (MEL-SYD), AA7365 (SYD-LAX), then any of several LAX-SEA options (most codeshare on AS planes), then AA6964 (SEA-LAX), AA73 (LAX-SYD), then AA7327 (SYD-MEL). You can buy the MEL-SYD-LAX flights and the SYD-LAX-SEA options on several places, but finding them all together seems to not show up. I need the late departure from MEL in order to maximize time with my daughter, and the late departure from SEA in order to maximize time working. It's easy to find a 9:30ish departure from MEL, but that means leaving home when my daughter wakes up rather than playing with her for the morning.

Comment: Eh? I am shown MEL-SYD-LAX-SEA on aa.com as a single itinerary! I am also getting MEL-LAX-SEA itineraries, with 7 to 12 hour layovers in LAX.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes - but not the times I want (big difference between a 9:30am departure at a 2pm departure when you're doing this trip on a regular basis and want to maximize time with small child). To be precise, I'll add the specific flight numbers to the question.  A 7 hour LAX layover is not an option for me.

Comment: Rather than looking on a random online agency, why not look on the AA website to book these flights? And/or phone the AA sales line? That's by far and away your best bet for getting these onto a single AA booking

Comment: @Gagravarr - I tried the AA website first.  Then I tried to look up the AA sales line: "AUD 80 reservations service charge may apply for tickets issued through reservation center."

Comment: Make sure you use the AA multi-city option on their website - it's very very good at booking complicated itineraries. If not, phone up AA and tell them you can't book the ticket online, they should waive any offline fees if the website can't/won't do something

Comment: @Gagravarr I tried the multi-city option.  Maybe they should waive the fees on the phone, but maybe they won't.  Who knows.  Of course last time I had to go through their phone system, it took me 3 hours to finally get the issue cleared up - at one point I was directly reading the person something on the AA webpage and she was telling me the webpage didn't say that.  So, not keen to call up.

Comment: QF17/AA7365 is currently only flying three days a week: Tuesday, Saturday and Sunday. And I think it is a seasonal one; there don't seem to be any flights after 24th April. This is probably why you can't find it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I appreciate the comment, but that's not the issue.  Right now on the AA website I can buy the MEL-SYD-LAX and back legs and the SYD-LAX-SEA and back legs (with the same SYD-LAX flights on both tickets).  I just can't buy that as MEL-SYD-LAX-SEA.  I've managed to get something else approximating this, but would prefer this.

Comment: I've just had a play with the AA multi-city tool, breaking it into MEL-LAX, LAX-SEA, SEA-LAX and LAX-MEL, and it seems to be giving me the flights you want for a random Sunday to Tuesday

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/) lets you search like this, but it won't actually book your flights. Use the "advanced routing codes" option and the specific flight syntax F:AA1234" (for AA 1234).

You'd then need to find a travel agent who can actually book your ticket, or try to find the same itinerary on Google Flights or [Hipmunk](https://www.hipmunk.com/tailwind/hiphacks-find-even-cheaper-flights-ita-routing-language/) (using the secret Hipmunk search codes). Be sure to set the "sales city" correctly or you may find a fare that you aren't able to book in your country.

Of course, this doesn't guarantee the ticket will come on an AA ticket, so you'd need to confirm that as well before booking since that's important to you.

Comment: Ringing up the AA ticket sales line is the best way to get this "plated" onto 001-stock so it's an AA ticket! Second best is a competent non-online travel agent

Answer (score 0):

Hi agree with you that buy two or more separates tickets is a strong risk , that I do not really suggest .

Then the result of your query is this :

The number next to the flight number is the departure day ( 1 monday , 2 tuesday etc )

12QF:AA7407  3    MEL 1 SYD 3  1400    1525   0 16MAR16 23MAR16 330  1:25
6QF:AA7365  27   SYD 1 LAX B  1825    1405   0 13MAR16 22MAR16 744 13:40

**AS**

1   AS 477  147  LAX 6 SEA    0600    0844   0 13MAR16 17MAR16 739  2:44
 2   AS 477  2    LAX 6 SEA    0600    0844   0 15MAR16 15MAR16 73G  2:44
 3   AS 477  3    LAX 6 SEA    0600    0844   0 16MAR16 16MAR16 738  2:44
 4   AS 477  5    LAX 6 SEA    0600    0845   0 11MAR16 11MAR16 73G  2:45
 5   AS 477  4    LAX 6 SEA    0600    0845   0 10MAR16 10MAR16 734  2:45
 6   AS 477  6    LAX 6 SEA    0600    0845   0 12MAR16 12MAR16 739  2:45
 7   AS 445  1    LAX 6 SEA    0635    0919   0 14MAR16 14MAR16 739  2:44
 8   AS 455  X56  LAX 6 SEA    0710    1000   0 13MAR16 17MAR16 739  2:50
 9   AS 455  4    LAX 6 SEA    0730    1018   0 03MAR16 10MAR16 739  2:48
10   AS 449  4    LAX 6 SEA    1010    1254   0 10MAR16 10MAR16 734  2:44
11   AS 475  123  LAX 6 SEA    1015    1255   0 14MAR16 23MAR16 739  2:40
12   AS 475  4    LAX 6 SEA    1025    1305   0 17MAR16 17MAR16 73G  2:40

### >

3AS:AA6964  5    SEA   LAX 6  1855    2135   0 11MAR16 11MAR16 737  2:40

1   AA 073  456  LAX 4 SYD 1  2150    0755+2 0 05MAR16 12MAR16 77W 15:05
 2   AA 073  X56  LAX 4 SYD 1  2150    0655+2 0 13MAR16 24MAR16 77W 15:05

3QF:AA7327  X6   SYD 3 MEL 1  1000    1135   0 11JAN16 25MAR16 737  1:35

Comment: Why is it a risk? Unlike many Airlines, AA actually has a published policy on mis-connects between separate tickets for when both flights are with OneWorld carriers

Comment: @Gagravarr Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Joel It used to be on an easily-linked page on the AA website, but then they went and re-arranged it, and seem to do some moderately often now... [Latest location is in this AA ticketing reference guide, last page, under "Oneworld Reaccommodations - Separate Tickets"](https://ssc.aa.com/prmportal_enu/AgencyReferenceFiles/Booking%20and%20Ticketing%20Index.pdf)